# What does this SQL query actually do?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just wanted to ask if anyone can help me understand what this query actually does?

```
select location, address
from warehouse D 
where not exists
    ( select * from product P, supplier S
      where P.supplier_no = S.supplier_no
      and   S.name = 'Azure Supplies'
      and   not exists
            ( select *
              from stock S
              where P.product_no = S.product_no
              and D.warehouse_no = S.warehouse_no ) ) ;
```

Comment: In general when asking this sort of thing, it is helpful to show your table structure as well, and what each row means. Does an entry in `warehouse` mean that that product type is usually stored in that warehouse, or does it mean that a specific item of product _is_ stored there?

Comment: I second @halfer here, http://sqlfiddle.com/ will come in handy

Comment: @halfer  I'll bare that in mind next time I ask a question like this. thank you for the suggestion and response

Answer (score 3):

`not exists ( select ... )` is `true`, when the select doesn't return any rows.

So the innermost `select` tries to find products with stock. Which products? Any that are selected by the middle `select` which in turn inverts the innermost query (i.e. it returns all products *without* a stock). This is joined will all known warehouses to get a list of warehouses which don't have any products from this supplier in stock.

It becomes more simple to understand when you use positive logic:

First, we create three sets:

- All warehouses (set `D`)
- All products by "Azure Supplies" (set `P)
- All stocks of the products in `P` and from warehouses in `D` (set `S`)

Note that there is another set `supplier S` but that's not what I'm talking about.

Now we filter those sets.

First, we remove all products which have a stock (inner `not exists`). That gives us the set of products without a stock.

In the final step, we remove all warehouses from the result where this set isn't empty.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer, makes it a lot easier for me to understand the query.

Answer (score 1):

you're actually trying to find all products made by 'Azure Supplies' that does not exist in the stock.

Answer (score 0):

This is in essence selecting a location and address from a table warehouse where there is not a supplier named 'Azure Supplies' and no products that relate to that supplier.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes a lot more sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

its selecting location and address from warehouse D where there is no supplier of name "azure supplies" which also does not exist in stock s.

all = conditions are just to show the common column values b/w table.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, the query is now making a lot more sense